# Data Cloud activation

Tags: marketing-cloud, datacloud

Trying to activate a segment to Marketing cloud

1. Allow Profile Business Unit Mapping Data is enabled.
2. Mapping for email is as follows the Party and Individual ID are refer back to Contact ID.
   [image]
   Am facing this issue not sure how to debug further,
   [image]

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389678&type=1